# Highest high in a range pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to label and change the color of the highest bar in the range. Instead, it paints all bars with the color and does not plot the label on the highest bar but on the last bar?

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Label', overlay=true)

highestHigh = ta.highest(high, 20)
lowestLows = ta.lowest(low, 20)

PmeU = if highestHigh
    label.new(bar_index, na, "Highest pirce was: " + str.tostring(highestHigh), color=color.green, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)

label.delete(PmeU[1])

barcolor(highestHigh ? color.blue : na)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ta.highest()` returns the highest price within the lookback period. It does not return if the current `high` is the highest. You need an additional check for that.

Coming to the issue with the `label`, it is because you always delete the previous one. I don't think you want to delete any label in your case.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Label', overlay=true)

highestHigh = ta.highest(high, 20)
lowestLows = ta.lowest(low, 20)

is_high = high >= highestHigh

PmeU = if is_high
    label.new(bar_index, na, "Highest pirce was: " + str.tostring(highestHigh), color=color.green, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)

barcolor(is_high ? color.blue : na)
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful,  Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.